# A word for teasing someone with information they desire

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Is there a word (or a better sentence) to describe the following concept:

Enticing someone by letting them know you have the information they seek, yet smugly refuse to divulge it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The verb *[tantalize](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tantalize#Verb)* is relevant.  Wiktionary shows two senses:
• to tease (someone) by offering something desirable but keeping it out of reach
• to bait (someone) by showing something desirable but leaving them unsatisfied

Note, in the latter of those senses, *[bait](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bait#Verb)* is used  to mean teasing, luring, or enticing someone with something they apparently desire, but keeping it out of their reach.

Answer (score 2):

When you deliberately (apparently) promise someone favours, money, position, information . . . but then fail to deliver, it's called **leading them on**.